# Symfony2 default configuration parameters

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to have a default configuration parameters in Symfony yeml configuration file. In case where the variable parameter is not available. For example. I have database name coming from Apache configuration, but if I run a command I would like to go with a default database, see below. The example is kind of twigi'ish

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database.name%"|default('database1')
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
```

Comment: What is the specific scenario why the parameter would not be defined?

Comment: Apache send ```SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME mydatabase``` but when I run symfony command, Apache is not part of the equitation and errors is thrown as there is no database name

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that would be to set the parameter to a default value, which I assume would be early in the configuration file. A theoretic example:

```
parameters:
    foo: bar

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

If parameters.yml contains a definition for the %foo% parameter, it will overwrite the previous definition. If parameter.yml does not contain a definition for %foo% however, it will use the earlier defined (default) value.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you *do* define `%foo%` in `parameters.yml`, subsequent runs of `composer install` will remove it (because it's not in `parameters.dist.yml`).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your default configuration in parameters.yml.dist, this way when someone new joins the project and runs:

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

He will be prompted to provide his environment specific values and so parameters.yml will be created.

Comment: While you can certainly do this, it has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way around this problem by using "database_prefix" as the default database and other databases just add a suffix to that.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "database_prefix%database.name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```